# Is there an elegant pyspark solution for the following ranking problem?

Tags: math, pyspark, data-analysis, ranking

is there an elegant function that exists for the following problem?

I've been tasked to create a function to determine the differences in days and rank the values. The closest positive number would rank as 0 and be the 'starting point'. From the starting point, depending on whether the ranked value is negative, or non-negative, the function would assign a rank to the value either positive or negative respectively.

| Datediff() | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| -50 | -3 |
| -32 | -2 |
| -1 | -1 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 14 | 1 |
| 32 | 2 |
| 128 | 3 |
| 254 | 4 |

My solution so far would be to separate the negative and positive numbers and use the window.partitionBy() function to assign the correlating rank. It would work, but I'm curious for a more elegant solution. :)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't understand the problem. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: It looks like you just want to sort the numbers? Then rank "0" the first nonnegative number, and rank the other numbers accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Window` to generate serial numbers to use as rank:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([(10,),(-10,),(5,),(-5,),(15,),(-15,)], ["dated_diff"])
window = Window.orderBy(df["dated_diff"])
df = df.select("dated_diff", row_number().over(window).alias("row_number"))
df.show()

+----------+----------+
|dated_diff|row_number|
+----------+----------+
|       -15|         1|
|       -10|         2|
|        -5|         3|
|         5|         4|
|        10|         5|
|        15|         6|
+----------+----------+
```

Then find rank of first positive number:

```py
first_positive_rank = df.filter("dated_diff>=0").first()["row_number"]
print(first_positive_rank)
>> 4

OR

first_positive_rank = df.filter("dated_diff<0").count() + 1
print(first_positive_rank)
>> 4
```

And finally subtract that rank from rank of all:

```py
df = df.withColumn("row_number", col("row_number") - first_positive_rank)
df.show()

+----------+----------+
|dated_diff|row_number|
+----------+----------+
|       -15|        -3|
|       -10|        -2|
|        -5|        -1|
|         5|         0|
|        10|         1|
|        15|         2|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: An alternative to `df.filter("dated_diff>=0").first()["row_number"]` is to count the number of negative numbers (this can be done even before sorting).

Comment: Yes, negative count + 1 is the rank of the first positive value.

Comment: Modified the answer for this.